# Replace XML text node with an element node

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I am using groovy, so an java implementation would also be fine.

I have

```
"""<TextFlow fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="20"><span>before</span>Less than 7 days<span>after</span></TextFlow>"""
```

I would like to wrap first level text node with a  tag. So I would like to get

```
"""<TextFlow fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="20"><span>before</span><span>Less than 7 days</span><span>after</span></TextFlow>"""
```

I have looked into XmlSlurper which doesn't deal with text nodes.  I have also looked into XmlParser which can handle text nodes, but I am not sure how to replace it with an xml element.  Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, hope it'd help someone else

```
@Grab('org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.5')
@Grab('jaxen:jaxen:1.1.4')
@GrabExclude('jdom:jdom')

import org.jdom2.*
import org.jdom2.input.*
import org.jdom2.xpath.*
import org.jdom2.output.*

def xml = """<TextFlow fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="20"><span>before</span>Less than 7 days<span>after</span></TextFlow>"""

Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(new StringReader(xml)) 
def urls = XPathFactory.instance().compile('//TextFlow/text()').evaluate(doc)

for(def c in urls) {
    int pos = c.parent.content.indexOf(c)    
    Element span = new Element("span")
    span.text = c.text
    c.parent.setContent(pos, span)

}

new XMLOutputter().with {
  format = Format.getRawFormat()
  format.setLineSeparator(LineSeparator.NONE)
  // XmlOutputter can write to OutputStream or Writer, which is sufficient for most cases
  output(doc, System.out)
}
```